# Allow C-w to kill a region only if it is selected

Tags: region, kill-text

Sometimes (rarely I would say) I press `C-w` by mistake and if the mark defines a non empty region, it gets deleted.

The few times this happened I just pressed undo, but I am afraid that sooner or later I will delete something without noticing.

Is it possible to tell emacs not to delete a region if it is not selected? It never happened to me to wanting to kill a region which was not selected, so this workaround would fix my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for:

```
(setq mark-even-if-inactive nil)
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.... but it broke multiple cursors! If I select a word and then use `mc/mark-next-like-this` and then type something, I get an error. Any way to make them work together?

Comment: @Nisba: Better ask the author of multiple-cursors.